# Tab changes color. Expected behavior or bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I recently notice in SFSE if I click any tab then it changes its color to blue and if I select other tab still the old tab remain in blue. Is this a expected behavior or a bug because I think old tab will change again into white.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for sharing this bug. This bug is a result from the `a:visited` link styling bleeding into navigation's menu links.

It was corrected by re-stating the menu's color for visited links (`#FFF`).

This update has been pushed to dev and will be updated in our next production build.