# Update to the navigation menu

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, site-layout

Allow myself to first introduce myself. My name is Josh and I'm a Senior Product Designer at Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow.

We are actively cleaning up a bunch of CSS and this morning I noticed an issue with this community's navigation menu and its lack of contrast. Here's the current menu:

[image: Current Navigation]

What I'm proposing is to reverse the color as a background color and make the copy white. Here's an example:

[image: New Proposed Nav - Still]

And here's an example of it in action:

[image: New Proposed Nav - Animated]

If there are no issues with this design change, I'll add to my list of design changes. The change would most likely go out either later this week or sometime next week (most likely mid-week).

Thanks for being a great community!

---

### Update:

This change is now live. If you notice any issues, please open a bug report and let us know. Thanks!

Comment: I think that contrast changed somewhat recently, and was actually [noted earlier this morning](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/tab-changes-color-expected-behavior-or-bug). I for one fully support this change!

Comment: @AdrianLarson I noticed that post as well. It's unrelated to this proposal. The navigation's `a` tag is inheriting the website's `a:visited` link styling. I'll get a fix for that up today.

Comment: Looks good to me/no complaints.

Comment: Thanks for making this change! This will look a lot better than the nav items have for the last few days.